# Getting error while fetch the records from the Network Path in .net project

Tags: c#, .net, docker, kubernetes

In .net i am using DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(_filePattern) to get the files from a Network Path (abc\xyz).
And when I'm running the Project using docker.
Getting error as:

**/app is appending at the starting of Network Path (/app\abc\xyz) and giving the error of Directory not found
where /app is coming from WORKDIR of docker

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-alpine AS base
RUN apk add icu-libs
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false
WORKDIR /app
RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata
EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: Have you tried to check if a directory exists inside the container? Docker command: `docker exec -i -t [Container Id or Name] bash`

Comment: Instead of "/app" just use "/" for WORKDIR.

Comment: By network path, do you mean a path like \\server\share ? If so, then that's not supported out of the box on Linux. Try googling 'mount SMB share on Alpine'.